Nuxt 3 and Cloudflare functions local development
I have a project that is using Nuxt 3 and Cloudflare functions for specific calls. From what I have read to run my workers locally I need to use wrangler and run this command wrangler pages dev <DIRECTORY-OF-ASSETS> which works fine if I run bun generate and then point wrangler to the .output/public directory but the issue is when I am working on both the frontend and the worker, because now I need to run generate every time I want to update the Nuxt side of things and this seems inefficient and can't see to find a bun generate --watch or some sort of similar command. Any recommendations or help would be appreciated
The only thing I could fine that was close was if I run bun --bun run dev and wrangler pages dev ./ but they run on separate ports so instead instead of being able to reference my functions like /function-url I have to have to specify the port of where my functions are running ie http://localhost:8788/functions-url and then because of this I have to allow cross origin on local which just leads to additional unnecessary code. I have also tried wrangler pages dev ./ --proxy 3000 and that doesn't seem to proxy as calling the function on my localhost:3000 results in a 404.
All that is needed to replicate is a Nuxt 3 project and a cloudflare functions directory and the basic install of wrangler to run the functions locally
